# Abp.AspNetCore.OData self-referencing loop when accessing odata/$metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, aspnetboilerplate

I am configuring a new OData project using this package. I have configured the project as per the documentation: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/OData-AspNetCore-Integration

When I access the route **/odata/$metadata**, I get the following exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop
>   detected for property 'declaringType' with type
>   'Microsoft.OData.Edm.EdmEntityType'. Path
>   'result.schemaElements[0].declaredKey[0]'.'

This is thrown in the `AbpUnitOfWorkMiddleware` class when `await _next(httpContext);` is called.

I can bypass the issue by adding `.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);` to the `Startup` class, but then this just keeps rendering the **$metadata** until the browser dies.

Could this be an issue with how the ABP framework handles this particular route? If I use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` without the ABP framework, then the **$metadata** route renders fine; it's actually returned as an XML document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Targeted solution

The solution is the same as the answer to [Disable Wrapping of Controller Results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47888802/8601760).

## One-liner quickfix

Alternatively, you can disable wrapping by default in the `PreInitialize` method of your module:

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpAspNetCore().DefaultWrapResultAttribute.WrapOnSuccess = false;
```

---

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked by adding AddODataNewtonsoftJson. you need to install a Nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.NewtonsoftJson

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson().AddODataNewtonsoftJson();
```