# How to control response wrapping in ABP on a per-route basis?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ABP (aspnetboilerplate) 7.0 thru ASP.NET Zero 11 and I'm trying to get OData working. I've followed the article over at ABP and I've taken inspiration from their sample.

The response of OData routes (`/odata` and `/odata/$metadata`) should not be wrapped. ABP does provide an attribute to prevent wrapping called `DontWrapResult`. However, since these routes are not on controllers that I have direct access to, I can't set the attribute.

The same question has been asked here: [Disable Wrapping of Controller Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888802/disable-wrapping-of-controller-results/47891580)
However, they wanted to disable wrapping altogether, which is not what I want to do.

The answer to that question is to use a `ResultFilter` to set the attribute's value. I have, however, found that setting the value thru the attribute also sets the value that comes from the injected `IAbpAspNetCoreConfiguration`.

For example:

```cs
public class ODataResultFilter : IResultFilter, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IAbpAspNetCoreConfiguration _configuration;

    public ODataResultFilter(IAbpAspNetCoreConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var methodInfo = context.ActionDescriptor.GetMethodInfo();

        var wrapResultAttribute =
            GetSingleAttributeOfMemberOrDeclaringTypeOrDefault(
                methodInfo,
                _configuration.DefaultWrapResultAttribute,
                false
            );

        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Equals("/odata/$metadata") ||
            context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Equals("/odata"))
        {
            wrapResultAttribute.WrapOnSuccess = false;
        }
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        // No action
    }

    private TAttribute GetSingleAttributeOfMemberOrDeclaringTypeOrDefault<TAttribute>(MemberInfo memberInfo, TAttribute defaultValue = default(TAttribute), bool inherit = true)
        where TAttribute : class
    {
        return memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<TAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()
               ?? memberInfo.DeclaringType?.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<TAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()
               ?? defaultValue;
    }
}
```

As soon as I hit `wrapResultAttribute.WrapOnSuccess = false;`, `_configuration.DefaultWrapResultAttribute` becomes false and every other request ends up not being wrapped. My front-end expects wrapped responses and thus the front-end stops working as soon as I hit an OData route once.

How can I manipulate this attribute and prevent wrapping for OData routes but leave the default + attribute-configured wrapping behavior for the other routes?

`GetSingleAttributeOfMemberOrDeclaringTypeOrDefault` method should work fine, except right now, since `_configuration.DefaultWrapResultAttribute` gets modified, a controller that doesn't explicitly set a `WrapResult` attribute will get the default, overridden by the last value set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `IWrapResultFilter`, which was introduced in ABP v6.5:

```cs
using Abp.Web.Results.Filters;
using System;

namespace AbpODataDemo.Web.Host.ResultWrapping
{
    public class ODataWrapResultFilter : IWrapResultFilter
    {
        public bool HasFilterForWrapOnError(string url, out bool wrapOnError)
        {
            wrapOnError = false;
            return new Uri(url).AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/odata", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        public bool HasFilterForWrapOnSuccess(string url, out bool wrapOnSuccess)
        {
            wrapOnSuccess = false;
            return new Uri(url).AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/odata", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
}
```

Add it to `WrapResultFilters` in the `PreInitialize` method of your module:

```cs
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebCommon().WrapResultFilters.Add(new ODataWrapResultFilter());
```

Reference:

- https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core#wrapresultfilters
- https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/sample-odata/pull/20

---

## OData with ABP v7.1 and later

`Abp.AspNetCore.OData` implements `AbpODataDontWrapResultFilter` to disable result wrapping for paths that start with `"/odata"`.

Add it to `WrapResultFilters` in the `PreInitialize` method of your module:

```cs
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebCommon().WrapResultFilters.Add(new AbpODataDontWrapResultFilter());
```

The rationale of letting library users configure this explicitly is to highlight this interaction between the default result wrapping and OData use case.

References:

- https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/OData-AspNetCore-Integration#result-wrapping
- https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/6375

Comment: Thanks! This behaves exactly like what I was trying to achieve. I also see that the pull request you made was merged to the sample-odata repository, that's great. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: Hi. One question: what's the point of having "out bool wrapOnError" and also a boolean response? What's the meaning of each one? Thanks in advance.